# Patterns for exception handling in Spring Boot using beans or AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, aspectj, metrics

I have a Spring Boot server application where exceptions are caught, logged and handled when possible and when not possible they are handled by `@ControllerAdvice` as the last resort.

I want to add more logic for exception handling, for example, sending a metric to a monitoring solution on each exception. For example there's a Spring bean `MetricsBean` which is a service which sends metrics. Using `MetricsBean` is easy for errors which are handled by `@ControllerAdvice` because it's also a Spring bean.

However using `MetricsBean` is not as straightforward in such code:

```java
try {
  // business logic
} catch (Exception ex) {
  logger.error(ex)
}
```

because that would mean manually autowiring `MetricsBean` into each service class. Also `logger` object is not a Spring bean.

So I have a dilemma how do I send a metric from inside or around `logger.error()` method when the logger class itself is not a Spring bean. I'm wondering what the best practice is in such cases. Here're some of the options:

1. Should logger also be a Spring bean? (seems tedious and error-prone)
2. Should there be a custom `Exception` extending class which would be a Spring bean and will send a metric inside its constructor? (seems tedious and error-prone)
3. Should Spring AOP be used with the pointcut being `logger.error()` method?

I'm surprised that there's not an established solution for this pattern for such an established framework as Spring (most of the solutions focus on handling errors in `@ControllerAdvice`).

I'd like the solution to be as generic as possible (point 3 seems to win there) but perhaps there's a pattern which I'm missing.

Comment: Not clear if you have considered an AOP approach with pure `AspectJ`  (not Spring AOP). [Spring AOP Capabilities and Goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) and [Choosing which AOP Declaration Style to Use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-choosing) are in official documentation

Comment: An advise around `logger.error()` should be possible through `AspectJ`. Adding `aspectj` tag to get the right attention

Comment: not sure if I missed to add the tag or someone removed it after I added . Re added the same. please modify as required.

Comment: @R.G this use case seems very basic and common to me, do you know of libraries which provide such functionality?

Comment: How to configure `AspectJ` in Spring Boot project can be read [here](https://www.geekyhacker.com/2020/03/28/how-to-configure-aspectj-in-spring-boot/)

Comment: @R.G thank you for the link. I meant if there're libraries which already implemented such aspect based logging solutions so that I don't need to write it myself. Like I would just give this library a callback and it would invoke it on each log or something like that

Comment: Why would you need to wire the metrics bean into each Spring bean? Is it not enough to wire it into the aspect handling the errors? In any case, please present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not an ambiguous theoretical situation described only in prose. Make your problem reproducible if you hope for helpful answers. Otherwise, the answer will be just as generic and theoretical as your question. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best practice but I would use a UtilityClass as a facade exposing a static method. In that method, wire the metrics registry using `Metrics.globalRegistry` to avoid injection. This will avoid coupling the metric details from where it is used.

You can then either invoke the static method everywhere you are handling an exception (so besides `logger.error(ex)`) or combine this with your third option with the pointcut.

Simple example:

```
@UtilityClass
public class ExceptionUtility {
  public static void handleException(Throwable throwable) {
    Counter.builder("some.name.exception")
        .tag("name", throwable.getClass().getName())
        .register(Metrics.globalRegistry)
        .increment();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
    try {
    ...  
    } catch (RestClientException restClientException) {
      ExceptionUtility.handleException(restClientException);
    }
```

Comment: it's a good suggestion to use Metrics global registry, but I guess it's not generic enough because there might be other beans that could be used with exception